# Docker swarm nodes not showing up after restart

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I have created a local Swarm cluster.
When it was created, the cluster worked fine and when I ran `docker info` all the nodes was visible in the "Nodes" list.

After reboot, it looks like only one of the worker nodes have joined the cluster, yet. all of the nodes report that they all are members of the same cluster.

As shown in this picture.
All nodes have "swarm-master" in their SWARM column.
But in `docker info`, only the master and node 03 is visible
[image]

Are there any specific steps that I need to perform after a complete reboot.
`Docker-machine` reports that the nodes have been assigned new IP-addresses when restarted, so I guess that could be a problem (?)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having exactly the same issue. It seems to be a problem with the SSL certs. Getting really annoying having to recreate swarms on reboot.

Answer (score 0):

What is the swarm discovery backend ? I used consul, and had a similar issue; maybe it's just need to restart, or re-create the discovery back-end (consul) container.